# How Add Desc Numbering in List Title Content Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have code in index.php at wordpress theme:

```
<div id="content">
   <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
   <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        Book Title: <span class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>. Writer: <?php the_tags(' '); ?>. Publisher: <?php the_category(', '); ?>. </span>
        </div>      
   <?php endwhile;  ?>
   <?php endif;?>
</div>
```

I want to look at my blog as follows :

```
........
5. Book Title: ..... Writer: ..... Publisher: ..... 
4. Book Title: ..... Writer: ..... Publisher: ..... 
3. Book Title: ..... Writer: ..... Publisher: ..... 
2. Book Title: ..... Writer: ..... Publisher: ..... 
1. Book Title: ..... Writer: ..... Publisher: .....
```

What code should I add and placed where ?

Comment: change your question title. Are you want author names or change order?

Comment: I want put number before title, and number ordering is desc.

Comment: I have added the answer. if this helpfull vote up.

Answer (score 1):

Add increment value

```
<div id="content">
     <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
     <?php $i = 1; ?>
     <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        Number: <?php echo $i++; ?>Book Title: <span class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>. Writer: <?php the_tags(' '); ?>. Publisher: <?php the_category(', '); ?>. </span>
        </div>      
   <?php endwhile;  ?>
   <?php endif;?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank for your answered. This for ASC.

Comment: Halo [Mr.Ghulam Ali](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4035101/ghulam-ali), above code not function if use page navigation. Can you share another solution? thank.

Answer (score 1):

To have **descendant numbering**, you first need to get the total post count and then subtract 1 in each pass of the while loop.

```
<div id="content">
   <?php if ( have_posts() ) : $post_nr = $wp_query->post_count; ?>

   <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <?php echo $post_nr--;?>. Book Title: <span class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>. Writer: <?php the_tags(' '); ?>. Publisher: <?php the_category(', '); ?>. </span>
        </div>      
   <?php endwhile;  ?>
   <?php endif;?>
</div>
```

Comment: Good your answered. My problem is solved. Thank for xphan.

Comment: Halo [Mr.xphan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5171359/xphan), I haved problem now. This code not function if use page pagination. Can you have another solution? Thank.

Comment: I suggest you open a separate thread to this question. Also have a look at this example: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-count-posts-in-paginated-loop